# Recursive functions regarding index (Python)

Tags: python, function, recursion, fibonacci

The following code prints out a Fibonacci sequence from 0 to 7.
There is a recursion within the function where it calls itself and I have not been taught this. Initially I thought that the recursion was indexing the iterables inside range, but the code is not the same as indexing and seems arithmetic.

```
def fib (x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    elif x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib (x-1) + fib(x-2)

for i in range (8):
    print (fib(i), end=",")
```

I was not expecting anything to happen as this is a question for a practice quiz. I tried to ask chatgpt but I don't always trust them.

Comment: Recursion is just that: calling itself.

Comment: `fib` computes a *single* Fibonacci number recursively (and about as inefficiently as you can imagine). If you want a series of numbers, it's *far* more efficient to output the numbers as you generate them. (Print a number, then use it to compute the next one, repeat.)

Comment: It's a test question and I am wondering what is happening at line 7.

Comment: At line 7 the function is constructing the value of the N-th fibonacci element as a sum of the N-1st and N-2nd element, which it calculates in a recursive manner.

This is the most basic toy example to demonstrate recursion (think of it like "inception" :-D). It's a bit of a mind twister at first, but once you figure out the pattern, it's always the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm too late but I hope this is of some help to you or someone else.

Don't worry about not understanding certain things about recursion, I wasn't taught it either and at first approach it can be quite confusing.
Maybe you can understand better if you see it in a more visual way about what happens in line 7 and how the numbers 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13 are obtained.

I will illustrate a step by step of what happens with the first 6 numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5)

[image: Illustrated Fibonacci Step by Step]

The function uses the fibonacci property, which says that each number in the sequence is the sum of the previous two. Then, they are calculated recursively by adding the results of the previous function calls with the decremented values ​​(x-1 and x-2).

If the function could talk, it would basically be:

- *Receives a number
- Is that number 0 or 1?
- Yeah? then ready,
  take the corresponding 1 or 0.
- No? Okay, we'll run the function again with this number until we get either 0 or 1, and then we'll add all the 0's and 1's together.

As you can see, it takes each number and applies the function to it until they are reduced to 0 or 1.

I hope that with this you can understand what happens in line 7 of your code.